# Try to make input file Not Required but it still Required in Django Python

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Hi im still learning django and python, i made function to upload file, but i want the file is not required.

heres my code:

model.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
   status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Pending")
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='attachments/file/%Y/%m/%d/%P', blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def new_ticket(request):

form = TicketForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    
    form = TicketForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid() :
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.owner = request.user
        form.save()

        if form.docfile == 'docfile' :
            newdoc = TicketForm(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

        return redirect('helpdesk:dashboard')
documents = Ticket.objects.all()
return render(request, 'helpdesk/new_ticket.html', {'form':form,'documents':documents})
```

forms.py

```
class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
   status = forms.CharField(required=True)
   docfile = forms.FileField(required=False)
   class Meta:
       model = Ticket
       fields = ('status', 'docfile')
```

new_ticket.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="status">Status</label>
    {% render_field form.status class="form-control"%}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="docfile">File Upload: </label>
    {% render_field form.docfile required=false class="form-control"  %}
    
</div>
<hr>
<input class="form-group button_main btn-lg" type="submit" value="Send" style="border: 0px;"></form>
```

i already tried some solutions from this link :

[Django ModelChoice field is set to required=False but is still required in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877212/django-modelchoice-field-is-set-to-required-false-but-is-still-required-in-the-b)

[Django Make ContentType Not Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592823/django-make-contenttype-not-required)

[Django form always shows error "This field is required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806059/django-form-always-shows-error-this-field-is-required)

[Django TextField always is required, despite blank=True,Null=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956163/django-textfield-always-is-required-despite-blank-true-null-true)

[Django - Form template throws "This field is required" for Imagefield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409233/django-form-template-throws-this-field-is-required-for-imagefield)

but the input field still required, i try to false it from javascript and jquery too but its still required. i try to not render it and just add it to raw html and it still required.

[Image from console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS9qa.png)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this options:

#forms.py

```
from django.forms import TextInput, ClearableFileInput

class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['docfile'].required = False

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ('status', 'docfile')

        widgets = {
            'status': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',},),
            'docfile':ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',},),
        }
```

#new_ticket.html

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.status.label }}
    {{ form.status}
    {{ form.docfile.label}}
    {{ form.docfile}}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Note: Here I am Using Bootsrap CSS classes in forms.py for Styling, you can use a custom CSS class too.

Comment: Hi @eagele thank you for answering, i try your code but it still doesnt work, i wonder why ?

Comment: Hi, can you explain what happens when you submit.

Comment: it will save the data and the file, but i cant save it when input type file is null it said it must required the file. i want to make input type file optional. so i can add the file if i have, i already try your code too but the result still same the input type file still have attr required.

Comment: can try this please in #forms.py: 'docfile': ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'required': False})

Comment: oh my im sorry look like im careless all the code above is work but i forget to delete the required from javascript in document ready thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had something like:

```
class UpdateProfileForm(ModelForm):
    avatar_image = ImageField(widget=FileInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["avatar_image", "bio", "location", "birth_date", "zip_code"]
```

When I change to:

```
avatar_image = ImageField(widget=FileInput, required=False)
```

Looks like when using a defined form field with widget, FileInput, the required is set to True by default (despite me having it as null=True, blank=True in the model and even removing 'required' from a manual file input element in html -- weird -- but that's how it is I guess).